# Cómo eliminar caracteres especiales sin eliminar los espacios de un String

Tags: java, regex

Tengo la siguiente cadena, nombres = "YULISA ADALI ORDO?EZ ESCOBAR". Necesito que sólo se elimine el caracter especial respetando los espacios, así es como elimino el caracter pero también elimina los espacios:

```
nombres = "YULISA ADALI ORDO?EZ ESCOBAR";
nombres = nombres.replaceAll("[^\\w+]", "");
```

Comment: Entonces puedes indicar que conserve los espacios incluyendo el carácter espacio :)

Comment: Me puedes decir, como se hace?

Answer (score 3):

¡Ya ibas por muy buen camino! Como estás negando con `^`, sólo dile que no reemplace alfabéticos ni espacios. Literalmente, pon el espacio en el conjunto de carácteres a no reemplazar `[^\\w ]` (ahí está el espacio al lado de `\\w`). También sacamos el `+` para que la expresión diga "no reemplaces ninguna secuencia de alfabéticos y espacios de 1 o más elementos".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombres = "YULISA ADALI ORDO?EZ ESCOBAR";
        nombres = nombres.replaceAll("[^\\w ]+", "");
        System.out.println("la cosa es: " + nombres); 
        // salida: la cosa es: YULISA ADALI ORDOEZ ESCOBAR
    }
```